# Installing Ubuntu first time, having problem to install Asus drivers!

Tags: 12.04, installation, drivers, asus

I am new in using Linux OS. For now I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC. The problem that I found is that my Motherboard seems to not support Linux drivers. I know that because during installation it's blocked with a black screen full of errors/ codes or something like this and from all that list I recognized the name of my Motherboard **M2N-E-SLI**.

For now I running the Ubuntu from DVD and trying to understand how to install it to my PC. I read to **ASUS** website about this and they have some application who let me install Linux drivers, I downloaded it and I don't know how to run it.

Pls help me to resolve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is 64 bit, make sure you downloaded the 64 bit image.
(This must be a comment but I don't have rights to comment)